# Exporting a PNG of a zenmap topology from a Nmap XML file

Tags: python, nmap

I need help exporting the zenmap network topology graph to a PNG file automatically without  having to open the zenmap and doing it manually.

I found [a script on github](https://gist.github.com/bonsaiviking/8062547) but it's showing me an error:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print """{0} - Output a PNG from Nmap XML
        Usage: {0} <scan.xml> <out.png> <width_in_pixels>""".format(sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        from zenmapGUI.TopologyPage import *
    except ImportError:
        import sys
        sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/bin/zenmap")
        from zenmapGUI.TopologyPage import *

    t = TopologyPage(NetworkInventory(sys.argv[1]))
    pix = int(sys.argv[3])
    t.radialnet.set_allocation((0,0,pix,pix))
    t.update_radialnet()
    t.radialnet.save_drawing_to_file(sys.argv[2])


    pradeep@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python nmaptopng.py /home/pradeep/Desktop/topology.xml /home/pradeep/Desktop/xxx.png 500
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "nmaptopng.py", line 17, in <module>
        t = TopologyPage(NetworkInventory(sys.argv[1]))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zenmapCore/NetworkInventory.py", line 145, in __init__
        self.open_from_file(filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zenmapCore/NetworkInventory.py", line 315, in open_from_file
        parsed = NmapParser(path)
    TypeError: nmap_parser_sax() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I tried looking for the `NetworkInventory.py` file in zenmap but failed to understand the problem! Can anyone help me with this?